# Failing transaction [not out of gas] but error during execution of function

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets, vyper

I am new on smart contracts and have been experimenting with vyper and deploying a smart contract to Ropsten network. I am calling a function on my contract and my transaction is failing. But I have no idea why. Any ideas on how can I debug the code?

Here is the contract source: [code](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xacf7a600d2595c4295d6097b5c78f67a8ac84ff5#code)
Here is a failed transaction: [ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc1677ce0d08f99d1d6d105dbc7d6ec157e504565e8a072a8a7b2334348d49569)

Answer (score 0):

In the code of the `endAuction()` function there are two checks:

`assert block.timestamp >= self.auctionEnd`
and
`assert not self.ended`

Judging by the fact that `self.ended` is still `false` on your contract, the error was not caused by the second check. That leaves only `assert block.timestamp >= self.auctionEnd`. And lo and behold, `self.auctionEnd` is `3280457410 uint256` which in epoch time translates to Thursday, December 14, 2073 6:10:10 AM GMT. That renders check `block.timestamp >= self.auctionEnd` as `false` and triggers a Panic error.